# Disabling hover rule from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to disable a `:hover` rule when certain JavaScript code is triggered.

My css looks like this:

```
.headerfoldout a{
    background-color: red;
}
.headerfoldout a:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

When this JavaScript is triggered, I change the headerfoldout color, but I want it to remain the same color, even when hovered.

The JavaScript I use to set the css is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("headerfoldout").setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
```

Comment: it's bad but you can add `!important`

Comment: Thanks! i didn't think of that. Not clean tho :)

Comment: remove the class.

Comment: so add another class and CSS Specificity will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the styles with JavaScript is safer to do it with CSS and using classes in Js:

```
.headerfoldout a {
    background-color: red;
}

.headerfoldout a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.green.headerfoldout a, .green.headerfoldout a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

And in the Js:

```
// without checking the classname
document.getElementById("headerfoldout").className += " green";
```

Safer approach:

```
// checking the classname
var element, name, arr;
element = document.getElementById("headerfoldout");
name = "green";
arr = element.className.split(" ");
if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
    element.className += " " + name;
}
```

**Note:** I prefer `className` over `classList` because [it will work in all browsers](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp).

### Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, `classList` could be used to simplify the code:

```
 document.getElementById("headerfoldout").classList.add("green");
```

But be careful, **it is not supported in IE9**.

Comment: This could be simplified to `element.classList.add(name)`

Comment: Thanks, that works. And your approach does make more sense.

Comment: @monners I added a note which explains why I used the `className` attribute

Comment: Cool cool.  Might wanna add both examples to your answer, then you've covered all bases.

Comment: nice suggestion @monners